# Is there a way to set the type of `this` on an interface?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a TypeScript declaration file for a vanilla JS library. The main function takes a config argument that can contain functions, like this:

```js
interface Config {
  id: string
  onOpen?: () => void
}
```

All of the properties from `config` are added to an object main function of another type, `Foo`:

```js
interface Foo {
  someKey: number,
  onOpen: () => void // Set to the onOpen function passed to mainFunction
}


function mainFunction(config: Config): Foo
```

Since the functions from `config` are only called within the context of the `Foo` object, the `this` keyword should be in the scope of `Foo`. This means that the following were passed to `mainFunction`...

```js
mainFunction({
  id: 'abc',
  onOpen: function () {
    alert(this.someKey)
  }
})
```

...`this.someKey` would be retrieved from the `Foo` object.

Is there a way to say that any functions on the interface `Config` with have `this` keyword of type `Foo`?

Comment: Because `Config.onOpen()` could theoretically be called from anywhere, I don't think TS would have a way to define that `this` will definitely be `Foo`. You *might* be able to cast it, but that would remove some of the type safety provided by Typescript. Personally, I'd probably change `Config` to use `onOpen?: (foo: Foo) => void`, then you can use the reference passed to the function, safely knowing it will always be in instance of `Foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) to the callback type:

```
interface Config {
  id: string
  onOpen?: (this: Foo) => void
}
```